# coding is still showing the fieldname not the caption

Tags: c#, asp.net

In following code, I want to show not PATIENT NAME but "NAME" as it is in the caption
but it's still showing "PATIENT NAME". Is there another to use beside caption?

```
<Templates>
<DetailRow>
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gvDetail" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="gvDetail" 

 AutoGenerateColumns="false"
 DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="1100px" KeyFieldName="ID_KEY"
 OnBeforePerformDataSelect="detailGrid_DataSelect" OnInit="gvDetail_Init">
 <Columns>
      <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ID_KEY" Visible="false">
      </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
     <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="PATIENTNAME" Caption="Name" VisibleIndex="2">
     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></CellStyle>
           <HeaderTemplate>
           <div style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; float: left;">
              <div style="float: left;">
              <dx:ASPxImage runat="server" ID="imgFilterDetail" ToolTip="Show/hide grid  filter" ImageUrl="~/Content/Images/GridFilterButton.png">
              <ClientSideEvents Click="ImageClickDetail" />
              </dx:ASPxImage>
              </div>
             <div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 4px;">
                      Patient Name
              </div>
                 </div>
                              </HeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: why do you have `<div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 4px;">
                      Patient Name
              </div>` in your header template?

Comment: Good catch NP, I removed this but still issue remains

Comment: If you're going to use a HeaderTemplate then why not keep the above div you removed and replace Patient Name with Name? Or better, `<dx:ASPxLabel ID="PatientNameHeaderLabel" runat="server" Text="Name"/>`